# How to fit a Image to UIView in IOS7

Tags: uiview, uiimage, ios7

I'm getting a problem in setting a background image to UIView in IOS7 .I'm not getting what all the scaling changes have done in IOS7.where as in IOS6 it works well but not in IOS7.here is the code which im trying to do

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.bounds.size);
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"loginframe.png"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

mloginview=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,70,260,320)];
mloginview.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
[self.view addSubview:mloginview];
```

This is the image which trying to fit to mloginView

[image: This is the image which trying to fit to mloginView]

screen shot which is getting in the simulator[output]

[image: screen shot which is getting in the simulator[output]]

Comment: This question brushed into NDA based SDKs. The OP is not allowed to discuss iOS 7.

Answer (score -1):

We can't discuss iOS7 publicly because is is under NDA. Go to the Apple forums. In saying that backgroundColor isn't a good way to do this. Just add an image view

Comment: I have tried the way which you have told(with UIImageView).still i'm not getting the correct output